# What is causing my server to crash when opening a file?

Tags: c#, iis, azure

I have a simple architecture for a certain project, which goes a little like this:

1. User Requests a file using ASP.NET MVC
2. Local Cache is checked for said file, if it does not exist in cache, then the file is pulled from Azure Blob storage.
3. By this point, the file is definately on my server, and I know the path.
4. I use a third party library to open the file, my providing it with the path, it then returns a class structure which I use to create a View for the user.

This works, 99% of the time. Files are either found in cache or downloaded, then opened using the third party code, before being presented to the user in nice Views.

However, there is a curious set of circumstances which I can replicate, which causes my production server to crash outright.

They are the following:

- File is not found in cache
- File is downloaded from Azure
- Third party (unsafe) library crashes while opening the file
- Takes the server with it.

I understand that I am asking for some trouble using an unsafe library, but what is most odd is that if I try a second time, the file will now be in cache because Azure was correctly used the first time, Azure isn't hit, the file will opened successfully.

The third party library essentially sees the file downloaded from Azure as corrupt, yet when the exact same code tries to open the exact same file without the Azure involvement, it opens no problem.

So I initially blamed Azure, perhaps I wasn't closing the file correctly. I have checked though, the filestream I use to get the file is definately being closed (it is wrapped in a using statement).

Code is below, (forceRefresh is a flag which I can set to always skip the local cache). Path is set to a location on my server ~/tmp

```
if (!File.Exists(path) || forceRefresh)
{
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

   ICloudBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
   using (var filestream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.Read))
   {
        blob.DownloadToStream(filestream);
   }

}
```

Weirder still, I repeated my test, this time, after the crash, I delete the file from the cache so that Azure will be hit again. It is, and the file opens without causing the crash.

So it only seems to happen first time opening a file downloaded from Azure - I can cause the error on demand simply by recycling the application pool.

Has anybody got any suggestions as to how I can even debug this? I cannot replicate on my local development machine.

**EDIT: Answers to feedback from Richard Turner**

I don't believe that the blob retrieval code is what is causing the exception. The reason for this is that in the event that the web app does crash, this is after the file has been downloaded. I can even verify that the file is not corrupt as I can open it on subsequent retries.

You are exactly right with what you have said with regards to 'unsafe' - I have wrapper code which performs PInvoke - It does not however, implement IDisposable and this is something I will look into immediately. As for performance, at this point I am not worried about that.

With regards to reorganising my code, the "cache" which I decribe is in fact a set of files on disk, so in essence I already have the structure which you recommend. The 3rd party library only accepts a filepath as input, so I had to follow that route.

In answer to your final questions:

1. Reading the blob as a stream is the only way I can see available to read it? I don't see any API methods to get it as byte[] or anything else for that matter.
2. FileStream does not need to be Read/Write, but changing it did not improve things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exception handling for this sort of thing:

```
      try
        {
            //connection here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            // will give you the error if no connection and you can get an idea why it crashes
        }
```

Comment: 1. This is a web app, MessageBox.Show will do nothing. 2. Exception handling doesn't catch this.

Answer (score 0):

> It's difficult to determine what's going wrong as you don't post
>   enough of your code to, for example, understand how you're
>   instantiating/destroying instances of your 3rd party component and how
>   you're passing the data to said component.

However, here are a few things to consider:

Tacit is right: Your app is crashing because it's throwing unhandled exceptions. Assume that any operation that interacts with the storage services will fail. If they haven't yet, they will.Therefore, implement an exception handler that wraps your blob retrieval code and implement retry semantics if necessary. You might want to add [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) logging in order to log crashes and failures within your app code.

I don't quite understand what you mean by the 3rd party library being "unsafe". Do you mean "unsafe" as in it's a native library that you have to PInvoke into?

Depending on how your code instantiates/destroys the 3rd party component, you may find that the component remains in memory after it is used and it may maintain some state that gets corrupted/confused. If you HAVE to use such a component, consider writing your own PInvoke wrapper that also supports IDisposable and force the component to unload when you're done with it. Note, however, that this may result in a perf hit.

One other thing to consider: Perhaps you should re-organize your code a little so that the 3rd party component only ever loads the file from disk.

1. If the file is NOT on disk load it from Azure (wrapping operation with necessary exception handlers) and store it on disk
2. Load file's contents from disk and pass to 3rd party component

In addition, there are a couple of other things to look in your code:

1. Is there any reason you're reading the blob as a stream rather than a byte[] or string?
2. Is there any reason you're creating a read/write filestream? If you're not writing to your stream, consider opening the stream in read-only mode.

> Update 2013-02-28 @ 16:47 PST - In reply to KingCronus' update above:

CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(...) returns a CloudBlockBlob object. CloudBlockBlob objects have methods for [DownloadByteArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.downloadbytearray.aspx), [DownloadText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.downloadtext.aspx) and, importantly, **[DownloadToFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.downloadtofile.aspx)**. This latter API may help alleviate the file corruption issue entirely!

It's entirely possible that the native component you're PInvoking into could be trashing the running process outside the control of IIS.

If it's crashing because its input data (i.e. the file) is corrupt, then consider working out if you can pre-process the data to make it compliant with the component's requirements.

If the component continues to crash, especially because its internal state is broken, you might want to consider isolating the component from IIS by, for example, creating a Windows service that hosts an instance of your component. Such a service can be automatically restarted if it fails. You could communicate with the service hosting your component via WCF/NamedPipes/etc. and marshal data back and forth. However, I think I'd rather consider replacing the component entirely if at all possible rather than introduce last-resort mechanisms like this!

Comment: Hi Richard, answering all of this in a comment will be tricky, so I have added some answers to my original question. Cheers

Comment: I hear you on the unhandledexception thing, but under ASP.NET that would/should throw a Server YellowPageOfDeath, not just bomb my app. My suspicion is that there is perhaps some lock on the file that lingers and when the 3rd party code tries to access it, it causes a problem. Exception handling won't help one bit if the exception is only thrown in unmanaged code will it?